# Why nspacl is null?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm querying the postgres system table `pg_namespace`, in particular I'm interested into the field `nspacl`, which as per documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/catalog-pg-namespace.html is a list of granted privileges to a 'namespace'.

What is not clear from the documentation is the case of `null` for this field, how is it to be interpreted?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name wouldn't this be around Postgres anyway? It is a Postgres system table, so I reckon it also applies to Postgres DB

Comment: Postgres and Redshift are substantially different database systems (regardless of what the Amazon marketing is trying to tell you). I wouldn't be surprised if the whole ACL/privilege system is also quite different.

Comment: fair... although the Redshift documentation page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_join_PG.html has a link to Postgres documentation page around table `pg_namespace`

Answer (score 0):

Based on some tests, it looks like that `null` value is for **newly created schemas** which **have not been granted** any sort of **permissions yet**.